# how do i find file-type in node.js?

Tags: node.js, undefined, file-type

I'm a newbie for node.js and I'm having a problem with the file-type package. I used it to get the type of a png file by using:

```
const buffer = readChunk.sync(filepath, 0, fileType.minimumBytes);
fileType(buffer);
```

But somehow, my fileType, `minimumBytes` get undefined. Could anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi there! I just checked out the [`file-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) npm package, it does not seem to export anything think like `minimumBytes`, perhaps that is why `fileType.minimumBytes` is undefined or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

thank u, I have check my file-type version. FileType.minimumBytes is available in 12.2.0 version, not the lastest 14.1.4 version. So may be that is my issue